# Ember.js routes load order causing undefined error

Tags: routes, ember.js, load-order

I've got a set of routes. Some routes I want to redirect in the case that the user is not authenticated, and others I want to redirect if the user IS authenticated.

The AuthenticatedRoute case is working, so I've implemented the following Routes for the other case:

```
App.NotAuthenticatedRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  beforeModel: (transition) ->
    if App.Auth.get('signedIn')
      return Ember.RSVP.reject();

  events: {
    error: (reason, transition) ->
      @transitionTo('home')
  }

App.RegistrationRoute = App.NotAuthenticatedRoute.extend
  setupController: (controller) ->
    controller.set('email', null)
    controller.set('password', null)
    controller.set('passwordConfirmation', null)

App.LoginRoute = App.NotAuthenticatedRoute.extend
```

Each route is in it's own file in my /routes directory. RegistrationRoute works exactly as expected. LoginRoute, however, throws an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'extend' of undefined login_route.js?body=1:2
(anonymous function)
```

The only reason I can think of for this is that `LoginRoute` is being interpreted before `NotAuthenticatedRoute` is loaded. If I change `NotAuthenticatedRoute` in `not_authenticated_route.js.coffee` to something like `AntiAuthenticatedRoute` in `anti_authenticated_route.js.coffee`, everything works.

How might I handle the load order?

I also solved the issue by putting my routes intended to be inherited from in an extensions directory, which gets loaded before the other files in the routes directory, which might be a decent workaround for the problem.

Comment: what type of build system are you using, if any? it seams to load the js files in rather alphabetical ASC order this is might the reason why it's working if you change the file names

Comment: I'm just using the rails asset pipeline at the moment. I'm not sure what effect asset compliation would have on the issue at the moment.

Comment: take a look http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html, I guess this statement is informative: *Directives are processed top to bottom, but the order in which files are included by require_tree is unspecified. You should not rely on any particular order among those. If you need to ensure some particular JavaScript ends up above some other in the concatenated file, require the prerequisite file first in the manifest. Note that the family of require directives prevents files from being included twice in the output.* it's stated that eventually setting pre-compilation to true should help

Comment: You can verify that order is the problem by looking at the order of the generated .js file.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `App.NotAuthenticatedRoute` is defined in `not_authenticated_route.js` then add a require statement in your definition of `App.LoginRoute`:

```
#= require not_authenticated_route

App.LoginRoute = App.NotAuthenticatedRoute.extend
```